# Runtime exception in optix 6.0.0 sample code

Tags: c++, optix, nvrtc

After downloading `optix6.0.0 sdk` and compiling the sample projects included, I encountered runtime exception when running any of the sample projects(e.g. `optixHello`, `optixWhitted`), with error message:

```
OptiX Error: 'NVRTC Compilation failed.                                                                                 
nvrtc: error: failed to load builtins for compute_30.'
```

My environment is: `vs2015`, `cuda11.0`.

Codes worked totally fine for `ooptix sdk 7.0.0` (cmake, compile, runtime), and most of the pre-compiled sample projects `.exe` for `sdk 6.0.0` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with `Optix 6.5`, and I solved it using `vc2017` with `cuda 10`.

The [release notes](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/optix-6-5-release/80707) linked from the NVIDIA developer forum suggests that `Optix 6.5` works for up to `cuda 10`. The same appears to be true for `Optix 6.0` from its [release notes](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/optix-6-0-release/70167).